# How to pass parameters through sql select statement?

Tags: php, sql

I need to pass two parameters by the name of "supplier" and "stock name" in below sql statement.

```
<?php
include_once("init.php");

$line = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM stock_details  WHERE stock_name ='" . $_POST['stock_name'] . "'");
$cost = $line->company_price;
$sell = $line->selling_price;
$stock_id = $line->stock_id;
$line = $db->queryUniqueObject("***SELECT * FROM customer_stock  WHERE name ='" . $_POST['stock_name'] . "'"***);
$stock = $line->quantity;

if ($line != NULL) {

    $arr = array("cost" => "$cost", "sell" => "$sell", "stock" => "$stock", "guid" => $stock_id);
    echo json_encode($arr);

} else {
    $arr1 = array("no" => "no");
    echo json_encode($arr1);

}
?>
```

thanks

Comment: please share the query you have tried so far, also the expected output.

Comment: This is the query. its passing only one parameter i need to pass two. SELECT * FROM customer_stock  WHERE name ='" . $_POST['stock_name'] . "'"

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that by "parameters" you meant "conditions".

```
"SELECT * FROM customer_stock  WHERE name ='" . $_POST['stock_name'] . "' AND supplier = '" . $_POST['supplier'] . "'"
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you want then... Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Could you please give me your skype id. I will explain my problem. I have a hard time understanding the code i am using.

Comment: Well... No, I'm sorry. If you can't tell us what you want to achieve, I'm afraid no one will be able to help you.

Comment: the problem is quite complex and i can't explain it fully here